# nginx returns 404 after I deployed with capistrano and configured nginx.conf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger, linode

I have deployed my rails app using capistrano following Ryan Bates 335 tutorial.

when I go to my URL i get a 404 error and I don't know why. Even when I run `sudo service nginx stop` it doesn't stop the server.

Right now I have the following setup

Linode server:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- rbenv
- ruby 1.9.3-p194
- PostgreSQL
- nginx-passenger

My nginx.conf lives in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections 8000;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
  server_tokens off;

    include /opt/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Seconds
    keepalive_timeout 20;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
      '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /home/aurelien/apps/my-app/shared/log/access.log; # I created a log file there
    error_log /home/aurelien/apps/my-app/shared/log/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  gzip_min_length 512;
  gzip_buffers 4 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
  gzip_types text/css text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/json application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
  # No gzip support for > IE6
  gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary           on;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##

    passenger_root /home/aurelien/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.37;
    passenger_ruby /home/aurelien/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /opt/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

in my rails app /home/aurelien/apps/my-app/current/config I have another nginx.conf file with the following

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXX.XXX.XX.XX;
    root /home/aurelien/apps/my-app/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;


    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    error_page 500 422 404 /500.html;
}
```

I really don't know what I did wrong and I don't know how to debug. I really hope to get my rails app online as soon as possible.

also when I run the command `cap deploy:update` it doesn't always update the files in the `current` directory. I am not sure why, even when the files on github are up to date. here is my `deploy.rb` for reference:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "XXX.XXX.XX.XX", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "my-app"

set :user, "aurelien"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 3
# set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control directory names
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:aurelien/#{application}.git"
# using local git
# set :repository, "file:///var/git/#{application}.git"
# set :local_repository, "aurelien@example.com:/var/git/#{application}.git"
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
# ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :branch, "master"

# after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases
before 'deploy:finalize_update', 'deploy:assets:symlink'
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:assets:precompile'

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
# after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

namespace :deploy do

  desc "restart passenger server"
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/uploads"
    puts "==> IMPORTANT!!! Now edit database.yml in #{shared_path}/config <==="
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    # run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/uploads"
    # run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "make sure local git is in sync with remote"
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    else
      puts "Git is in sync!"
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"

  namespace :assets do

    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => {:no_release => true} do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision) rescue nil
      if from.nil? || capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ lib/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run_locally("rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile")
        run_locally "cd public && tar -jcf assets.tar.bz2 assets"
        top.upload "public/assets.tar.bz2", "#{shared_path}", :via => :scp
        run "cd #{shared_path} && tar -jxf assets.tar.bz2 && rm assets.tar.bz2"
        run_locally "rm public/assets.tar.bz2"
        run_locally("rake assets:clean")
      else
        logger.info "Skipping asset precompilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end

    task :symlink, roles: :web do
      run ("rm -rf #{latest_release}/public/assets &&
      mkdir -p #{latest_release}/public &&
      mkdir -p #{shared_path}/assets &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/assets #{latest_release}/public/assets")
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: try "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop" and
"sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start" to stop/start your nginx server

Comment: when I run `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop` it shows:
aurelien@lipton:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
[sudo] password for aurelien: 
Stopping nginx: aurelien@lipton:~$. But when I refresh IP in my browser I still get the 404 nginx page

Comment: and when I run the start command it says `Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:1`

Comment: its bcoz u have'nt  keep nginx config files in /etc, in your case it should be /opt...its not an solution to your question...but recently i had deployed my app with same configuration on degital ocean, i don't know why u have 2 nginx.conf file..,i followed http://www.netaddict.co.za/blog/2013/02/18/up-and-running-with-digital-ocean-and-rails/  take a look at it may b it help you..for me it works..

Comment: I actually merged both nginx.conf files to have a single one in /opt/nginx/conf. Last time I ran `cap deploy:update` it actually removed the nginx.conf file???! Well I am still running errors with only one file.